# Finite simple groups of "smooth" order

Tags: gr.group-theory, finite-groups

Given a finite group $G$, let $p(G)$ denote the largest prime factor
of the order of $G$. For the purpose of this question,
we say that the group $G$ has *smooth* order if its order exceeds
the order of the largest alternating group ${\rm A}_n$ for which
$p({\rm A}_n) = p(G)$.

**Question 1:** Is it true that the only finite simple groups whose
order is smooth in this sense are ${\rm PSU}(4,2)$, ${\rm PSU}(4,3)$,
${\rm O}(5,7)$, ${\rm O}^+(8,2)$, ${\rm McL}$, ${\rm PSU}(6,2)$,
${\rm Fi}_{22}$, ${\rm PSL}(6,3)$, ${\rm F}_4(2)$, ${\rm O}^+(8,4)$
and $^2{\rm E}_6(2)$?

**Question 2:** Is it true that for every finite simple group $G$
of sufficiently large order, we either have $G \cong {\rm A}_n$ for
some $n$ or $p(G) > \log_2(|G|)$? —
And if *yes*, is $|G| > |{\rm E}_7(4)| \approx 10^{80}$
sufficiently large in this sense?

Comment: The Hall-Janko sporadic group HJ is a fairly near miss, but does not quite make it ( as you probably checked). If it is relevant to the question at the end, I just put a paper on aRxiV which (in its most recent incarnation) prove that if a finite group $G$ has a faithful complex character of degree $n$, then $G$ has an Abelian normal subgroup $A$ such that either $[G:A] \leq 60^{n-1}$ or else $[G:A] \leq m!^{\frac{n-1}{m-2}},$ where $m > 151$ is the largest integer such that $A_{m}$ is a composition factor of $G$. It might be relevant to your question.

Comment: Your Question 2 does not use the concept of smooth order.  Is that intentional?

Comment: @LSpice Yes, the term is used only in Question 1.